# C# Remove xml tag at specific position by index

Tags: c#, xml

I have this soap response stripped out of soap envelope:

```
<GetCaseDetailsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <GetCaseDetailsResult>
    <Cases>
      <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">noob</Name>
      <Description xsi:type="xsd:string">Student</Description>
      <Ref xsi:type="xsd:string">1234</Ref>
      <Status xsi:type="xsd:string">Open</Status>
    </Cases>
  </GetCaseDetailsResult>
</GetCaseDetailsResponse>
```

I want to get rid of tag `<GetCaseDetailsResult>` (and its closing part), but have the contents remain intact. I can't use tag names, I have to do it as generically as possible, which is why I think deleting by index is the best solution. So far, I have not found a way of doing this without deleting the child nodes.

This is what should be the end result:

```
<GetCaseDetailsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

        <Cases>
          <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">noob</Name>
          <Description xsi:type="xsd:string">Student</Description>
          <Ref xsi:type="xsd:string">1234</Ref>
          <Status xsi:type="xsd:string">Open</Status>
        </Cases>

</GetCaseDetailsResponse>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you fix the XML snippet to include the `xmlns:xsi` declaration, so that it is valid, you can use the `ReplaceWith` method of `XElement`, to replace the first child (`GetCaseDetailsResult`) of the root element with the first child's children, like so:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
doc.Root.FirstNode.ReplaceWith(((XElement)doc.Root.FirstNode).Elements());
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Output:

```
<GetCaseDetailsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="xsi">
  <Cases>
    <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">noob</Name>
    <Description xsi:type="xsd:string">Student</Description>
    <Ref xsi:type="xsd:string">1234</Ref>
    <Status xsi:type="xsd:string">Open</Status>
  </Cases>
</GetCaseDetailsResponse>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
var q = from node in doc.Descendants("Setting")
        let attr = node.Attribute("name")
        where attr != null && attr.Value == "File1"
        select node;
q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
doc.Save("output.xml");
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be not the solution for this question, unless I'm missing something. I don't have descendants named 'setting' and I did mention that I can't use attribute names to refer to anything inside the xml, i.e., it has to be as generic as possible.